# C++ - run-time crashing of linear probing program

Tags: c++, data-structures, hash

I wrote a program in C++ for hashing using linear probing. The code is showing no error at the time of compilation but when I run it, computer shows the notification that the program has stopped working. I am giving the entire code below. Please help me out.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
class Acc
{
    public:
        int iData;
        double dData;
        Acc(int id,double dd)
        {
            iData = id;
            dData = dd;
        }
        void displayAcc()
        {
            cout<<"iData = "<<iData<<"\n";
            cout<<"dData = "<<dData<<"\n";
        }
};
class Linear_Hash
{
    private:
        vector<Acc*> hashArray;
        int nElem;
        Acc* noElem;
    public:
        Linear_Hash(int max)
        {
            nElem = max;
            hashArray.resize(nElem);
            noElem = new Acc(-1,1.1);
            for(int i = 0;i<max;i++)
            {
                hashArray[i] = NULL;
            }
        }
        int hashfunc(int key)
        {
            return key%nElem;
        }
        void insertAcc(int id,double dd)
        {
            Acc* newacc = new Acc(id,dd);
            int hashVal = hashfunc(id);
            while(hashArray[hashVal]->iData!=-1&&hashArray[hashVal]!=NULL)
            {
                hashVal++;
                hashVal = hashVal%nElem;
            }
            hashArray[hashVal] = newacc;
        }
        Acc* search(int key)
        {
            int hashVal = key%nElem;
            while(hashArray[hashVal]->iData!=key&&hashArray[hashVal]!=NULL)
            {
                hashVal++;
                hashVal = hashVal%nElem;
            }
            if(hashArray[hashVal]->iData==key)
            {
                return hashArray[hashVal];
            }
            else
                return NULL;
        }
        bool deleteAcc(int key)
        {
            int hashVal = hashfunc(key);
            while(hashArray[hashVal]->iData!=key&&hashArray[hashVal]!=NULL)
            {
                hashVal++;
                hashVal = hashVal%nElem;
            }
            if(hashArray[hashVal]==NULL)
                return false;
            else
            {
                Acc* pTemp = hashArray[hashVal];
                hashArray[hashVal] = noElem;
                delete pTemp;
                return true;
            }
        }
};
int main(void)
{
    int key;
    char val;
    Linear_Hash lh(20);
    lh.insertAcc(100,100.1);
    lh.insertAcc(204,204.204);
    lh.insertAcc(105,105.10);
    lh.insertAcc(237,348.23);
    lh.insertAcc(209,923.23);
    lh.insertAcc(230,230.23);
    lh.insertAcc(403,348.34);
    lh.insertAcc(405,938.50);
    lh.insertAcc(450,348.23);
    lh.insertAcc(945,495.409);
    while(val!='x')
    {
        cout<<"Enter the key to be searched\n";
        cin>>key;
        if(lh.search(key)==NULL)
            cout<<key<<" could not be found\n";
        else
            lh.search(key)->displayAcc();
        cout<<"Enter the key to be deleted\n";
        cin>>key;
        if(lh.deleteAcc(key))
            cout<<key<<" has been deleted\n";
        else
            cout<<"Invalid request\n";
        cout<<"Do you want to continue\n";
        cin>>val;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am unable to use the debugger in this case as I don't know where the error is. I have also tried dry-running it on paper but wasn't able to pin point the bug.

Comment: What does the notification say?

Comment: [not the cause of the crash] This leaks memory: `noElem = new Acc(-1,1.1);` because you do not delete it in the destructor.

Comment: @doctorlove:- The notification just says that the program has stopped working. It doesn't say anything about the cause of the crash. I think that some out-of-bounds array access might be the reason. But I am unable to find the root of that access.

Comment: @kusur You could try using a debugger and at least get the stack trace to see which line the problem happens on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Near the top of main you do this:

```
Linear_Hash lh(20);
lh.insertAcc(100,100.1);
```

The first line sets up the vector:

```
for(int i = 0;i<max;i++)
{
    hashArray[i] = NULL;
}
```

So, before the second line you have a vector of `NULL`s.
The second line then does this:

```
    Acc* newacc = new Acc(id,dd);
    int hashVal = hashfunc(id);
    while(hashArray[hashVal]->iData ...
```

So, hashArray contains NULLS, then you try to look at `hashArray[hashVal]->iData` i.e.

```
NULL->iData
```

You should check `hashArray[hashVal]!=NULL` before you try to do anything with it.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. I was using the concept of commutativity of && operator and thought that both of these conditions will be tested but forgot that the parsing is done from left to right and hence `hashArray[hashVal]->iData` would be read first.

Comment: @kusur Glad it's sorted. You must deal with the memory leaks - you need a delete for each new